# bubble sort for linked list in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

i tried to implement buble sort for my university project and i have some problems.
i will be happy if you can help me with it.

```
void TrainManagerLinkedList:: Swap(TrainManager & x,TrainManager & y)
 {
  TrainManager temp;
  temp =x;
  x = y;
  y = temp;
 }

void TrainManagerLinkedList::BubbleSort()
 {
  TrainManagerLink* outerCurr = this->m_head;
  TrainManagerLink* curr = NULL;

  while(outerCurr != NULL)
  {
   curr = this->m_head;
   while(curr != NULL && curr->m_next != NULL)
   {
    /*if the current link greater then the next swap between them*/
    if (curr->m_data->GetDate() > curr->m_next->m_data->GetDate())
    {
     Swap(&(curr->m_data),&(curr->m_next->m_data));
    }
    else if((curr->m_data->GetDate() == curr->m_next->m_data->GetDate())&(curr->m_data->GetTime() > curr->m_next->m_data->GetTime()))
    {
      Swap(&(curr->m_data),&(curr->m_next->m_data));
    }
    curr = curr->m_next;
   }
   outerCurr = outerCurr->m_next;
  }
  /*now the list is sorted :)*/

 }
```

my data types

```
TrainManagerLink *m_head;
 TrainManagerLink *m_tail;
 int m_numOfElements;

class TrainManager
{
 char * m_firstStation;
 char *m_lastStation;
 char * m_origin;
 char * m_destination;
 int m_timeBetweenStations;
 Hour m_releaseTime;
 Hour m_arriveTime;
 Hour m_firstHour;
 Date m_Date;
 int m_standInstation;
 DelayersLinkedList delay;
}
```

the linked list should be sorted by date and hour.
but i have some compile problems.
i relly need your help
thank you,:)

Comment: Could you format ALL the code as code? Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact wording of your compiler errors?

Comment: This question is missing quite a bit of contextual information. Please read ["Be precise and informative about your problem"](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise), ["When asking about code"](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code) and ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: the comile error 
Error 12 error C2664: 'TrainManagerLinkedList::Swap' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TrainManager **' to 'TrainManager &'

Comment: I will admit, I am tempted to supply you with a merge sort algorithm instead.

Answer (score 2):

In general there are issues I would address as follows:

1. Your class TrainManager has char* members not std::string, and you are not managing the memory. Not to mention that all the members are private, which may give you issues when you try comparing its members.
2. You would do better to swap the "links" rather than swap the actual data inside them.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error is quite obvious.
Use `Swap(*(curr->m_data),*(curr->m_next->m_data));`
 instead of `Swap(&(curr->m_data),&(curr->m_next->m_data));`.